# Bootloader questions

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to learn about the android's bootloader.

However, I got into some questions :

1. There are the `SECURE BOOT` and `LOCK STATE`. The `LOCK STATE` (if enabled) makes all partitions to read-only mode (right?). So what is `SECURE BOOT`? Is it possible to disable it it?
2. Is it possible to boot (not flash) an unsigned image and pass kernel options using fastboot, while the bootloader is locked? By kernel options I mean override the boot state to green.
3. Is it possible to boot a temporary image on locked not-rooted stock device using fastboot?

Thanks for all the helpers!

Comment: If 2 and 3 were *that* easily achieved then there wouldn't be so many devices locked down and waiting for exploits or official unlocks...